# How to create an Azure Point-to-site Virtual Network through Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

How can you create a point-to-site Azure Virtual network using PowerShell?
All the articles that I find online are using the Get-AzureVNetConfig and the Set-AzureVNetConfig cmdlets, while this is really a hard one to maintain. I think there must be a better and cleaner way.
I tried the new RM cmdlets, and they created the virtual network, but couldnt create a point to site connection. Microsoft acrticles say that they are not supported yet, so am looking for any alternatives using either the old or new cmdlets.

Moreover, am wondering what does the command "New-AzureVirtualNetwork" actually does, as it doesnt get recognized in Azure Powershell 0.9 and 1.0 as well https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163537.aspx

Your help in this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've just published the instructions of creating Azure P2S VPNs with Azure RM PowerShell:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps/

You will need the most recent PowerShell release (1.0.2 or above). Please take a look and let us know if you have any questions.

Thanks,

Yushun [MSFT]

Comment: This answer has been flagged for removal because it is a link-only answer. Could you please expand this answer so it provides an answer to the question without requiring the reader to click to the linked webpage?

Answer (score 0):

At last they released an article with the steps needed to do it!

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps/